# How to position a dialog box to the centre of a window

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

Can anyone please tell me how to position a box to the centre of the window using JQuery. I will paste the code below :-

```
    

    $("#address_book").click(function (e)
      {
          .........

         ShowDialog(false);
         e.preventDefault();
        ........
      });

    function ShowDialog(modal){

    ....  
      $("#overlay").show();

      $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);

      if (modal)
      {

         $("#overlay").unbind("click");
      }
      else
      {
         $("#overlay").click(function (e)
         {
            HideDialog();
         });
      }
     }
```

I want the dialog box to the centre of the window. Can anyone please tell me how to do this

Comment: post your html & css code also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code is not jquery, but pure javascript, so it will work without any hickup

```
  var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog')
  dialog.style.top = ((window.innerHeight/2) - (dialog.offsetHeight/2))+'px';
  dialog.style.left = ((window.innerWidth/2) - (dialog.offsetWidth/2))+'px';
```

Same code using jquery

```
  $('#dialog').css({
      top: ((window.innerHeight/2) - ($('#dialog').height()/2))+'px',
      left:((window.innerWidth/2) - ($('#dialog').width()/2))+'px'
    });
```

Demo of the code, in different application
[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ihepel/16/edit)

**Note:
your #dialog should have, `position:absolute` in its css, inorder to position the that div**

Comment: In someplace we have to set the margin:auto so that the popup position is correct.  Hope it will help some one..

Answer (score 1):

jQueryUI dialogs automatically center themselves so long as you have placed all content in them before they're opened.

However they will always be centered relative to the browser window, and not any parent "container" element, because jQueryUI removes the element that's converted into a dialog from the DOM and re-appends it to `document.body`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in jQuery:

```
$("#dialog").css("margin-top", ($(document.height() - $(this).height())/2);
$("#dialog").css("margin-left", ($(document.width() - $(this).width())/2);
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

$('#mycustomdialogDiv').css({
      top: 100,
      left:100
    });

sometimes this code will not work for you with jquery, because jquery dialog box generate its own wrapper over your customdialogdiv element. in order to achieve it, use below code;
 $('#mycustomdialogDiv').parent('div').css({
      top: 100,
      left:100
    });

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height and width of the dialog you can just set:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -[HEIGHT/2]px;
margin-left: -[WIDTH/2]px;
```

The advantage of that is if the widnow is resized it will be in the center anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Best to do it with css and transform, since..

1. Different browsers already place dialogs in middle, but even then in different ways!
2. You can only recalculate its own width positioning with transform (not with margin, etc.)

```
dialog {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50vw;
    top: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0; /*reset some browser centering*/
}
```

And if you really need jquery for some reason just add a class with jQuery, using the above css

Answer (score 0):

@e-motiv  - sorry not enough rep to comment on yr post

```
dialog {
    position: fixed; /*change to fixed for scrolling pages*/
    left: 50vw;
    top: 50vh; /*change from vw to vh*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0; /*reset some browser centering*/
}
```